# Is there an app for the VMware client?

Tags: install, apps

Does anyone know if or how I can install a VMware client app on my Elementary OS?

Many thanks,

Shimon.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean, you can install [VMWare Horizon Client](https://my.vmware.com/en/web/vmware/downloads/info/slug/desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_horizon_clients/horizon_8) which lets you connect to an existing virtual machine that's already remotely hosted.

If you want to set up a new virtual machine to run on your computer, VMWare offers a variety of products for this, including a free one for non-commerial use [VMWare Workstation Player](https://www.vmware.com/products/workstation-player/workstation-player-evaluation.html).

As far as I know, the vast majority of VMWare's applications are designed to run on Linux natively.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have an existing remote machine I want to connect to, so I need the "client". I know that VMware has a download for this; what I need help with is installing it on Elementary OS. Thanks in advance.